# How can I run multiple regressions iterating over a dataframe using purr (preferably)?

Tags: r, for-loop, purrr

I'm trying to estimate a quantile regression model over a set of bounds. There are three bounds for each model and the values are stored in a data frame (tibble). For example,: the first iteration of the rq(.) model should use the values  `-0.029, 0.05, 0.054,`. I'm not sure where to start.

I'm not completely sure how I wish the output to be stored, but probably in one dataframe. Thats why I added `|> tidy()` at the end of the rq(.)-function.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
library(quantreg) # quantile regression
library(tidyverse)

# data
df <- tibble::tribble(
          ~ln_wage, ~female,
  2.39789527279837,       0,
  3.29026583516231,       1,
  2.38232005396821,       1,
  1.84845479788611,       1,
  2.72457950305342,       0,
  2.70805020110221,       0
  )

bounds <- tibble::tribble(
  ~lower_bounds, ~percentile, ~upper_bounds,
         -0.029,      0.05,         0.054,
          0.026,       0.1,         0.108,
          0.188,      0.25,         0.271,
          0.459,       0.5,         0.541,
          0.729,      0.75,         0.812,
          0.892,       0.9,         0.974
  )


# quantile regression model
rq(ln_wage ~ female, 
   tau=c(lower_bounds , percentile, upper_bounds ),
   data = df) |> tidy()
```

**EDIT:**

I've tried solving it with a for-loop, but it gives me an error:
"invalid tau: taus should be >= 0 and <= 1"

```
run_rqs <- function() {
  # Create an empty list to store the results
  results <- list()
  
  # Loop through the rows of the data frame
  for (i in 1:nrow(bounds)) {
    # Get the current row of the data frame
    row <- bounds[i, ]
    
    # Extract the values for tau from the current row
    tau_values <- c(row$lower_bounds, row$percentile, row$upper_bounds)
    
    # Fit a quantile regression model with the current tau values
    model <- rq(ln_wage ~ female, tau = tau_values, data = df)
    
    # Store the model in the results list
    results[[i]] <- model
  }
  
  # Return the list of models
  return(tau_values)
}

run_rqs()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "over a set of bounds"? `tau` represents a *quantile*, which must be between 0 and 1. What are the lower and upper bounds specifications supposed to do?  (AFAICT what you want to do will fail if you just run a single instance of `rq()` - you can take away the complexity of the `for` loop until you can get the machinery working as you want for a single instance)

Comment: Sure! You can estimate any amount of bounds in a single instance. tau = c(0.4, 0.5,0.75) should work (although I'm on the phone, and cant check , but I know this for sure). To be clear: I want to estimate 3 percentiles per iteration.

Comment: That's fine, but the first lower bound in your data set is negative (`bounds$lower_bounds[1]` is -0.029), which is what is breaking your code.

Comment: Ooops! That explains it! Thanks.